# knowing how to understand organisation structure without erd using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am joining a new company in which there are no Entity relationship diagrams. However the Primary and Foreign key constraints exists. The database is in SQL server, I just want what the best and fastest way to develop an understanding using the SP or querying in SQL would look like to best understand the relationship between tables and to map how everything is laid out.

Comment: Do you have access to database diagram ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate Entity Relationship (ER) Diagram of a database using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379038/how-to-generate-entity-relationship-er-diagram-of-a-database-using-microsoft-s)

Answer (score 0):

Just right-click on your "DB" and select "DB Diagrams" and then "New DB Diagram", then select your tables and add them to the diagram.
finally, you can auto-arrange them by clicking on arrange tables near to the zoom icon.